# additional selections in Google maps api (3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markers

Once I have created a map with multiple markers using google maps API, I want to additional selections to highlight a subset of markers displayed. I would like to do this without going back to the server. Preferably I would like to store data in marker or array. I could either substitute with new marker or overlay an image on top of the marker.  Can anyone propose example of how to do this - specifically part about adding image or change marker.

Example below...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, which assumes that when you load your page you have this data returned from the server in JSON.

data = [{
      latitude: 103.2,
      longitude: 12.3,
      isDiscountOutlet: false
    }, {
      latitude: 101.2,
      longitude: 11.3,
      isDiscountOutlet: false
    }
    ]

The basic approach is that we store that data in the browser, and use it to update the appearance of markers when changing a selection.

**Part 1: Create a global variable to store our markers in**

```
var storedMarkers;
```

**Part 2: Create a Map using the data from the server**

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(103, 11)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // Add the markers. We are going to store them in a global array too,
  // so we can access them later.
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    // Create one marker for each piece of data.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude),
      map: map
    });

    // Store that marker, alongside that data.
    var dataToStore = {
      markerObject: marker,
      dataAssociatedWithMarker: data[i]
    };

    storedMarkers.push(dataToStore);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**Part 3: Let's show all discount outlets, and hide all other markers, when someone clicks a button**

I'm assuming you have a DOM element (a button) with id 'discount'. I'm also going to cheat and use jQuery :)

```
$("#discount").click(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < storedMarkers.length; ++i) {
    var currentStoredMarker = storedMarkers[i];

    // Is this marker a discount outlet?
    if (currentStoredMarker.dataAssociatedWithMarker.isDiscountOutlet == true) {
      // Let's show it!
      currentStoredMarker.markerObject.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      // Let's hide it!
      currentStoredMarker.markerObject.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
});
```